# SpriteKit Game Not Filling Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I searched and I couldn't find my identical problem. My background image and nodes are all filling the screen properly, however on a 6+ the entire game leaves about .5 inch space on the top and bottom of the game. Even the status bar of the phone gets pushed down as well. On the 4s iPhone it works perfectly.  Here is where I think the problem lays:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

Comment: creating your scene size to the view size, and then setting aspect fill does not make sense,  also, whatever you are doing is MyScene is most likely causing the problem, so you need to post that

Comment: MyScene is very long, just looked through it and I cannot find anything that is restricting size. What should I do in regards to the aspect view then?

Comment: You pick one or the other,  you either pick a static size for your view and let aspect fill scale the scene, or you use .resizefill if you want the scene to be the size of your view

Comment: Added launch images for 6/6+ and seemed to fix the issue also did what you suggested. And now it works accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: ahh, it was kicking you into iphone 5 mode,  you should be using a xib now for your launch screen though.